# How to restrict amount of characters a user can enter?

Tags: java

For my program below, I want it so that the user must enter a word 2 or more characters long, but I do not know how to make that restriction.

This is a palindrome program, and it is used to test whether the word is a palindrome or not. It lets me enter a word of any length but I want to restrict to 2 or more, and if they enter only a one character word, a message should display "Wrong word".

```
import java.util.*;
class PalindromeTesterSamJiang1 {
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        int x=0;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Menu: Please select an option \n"
            + "1)Palindrome Tester\n"
            + "0)Exit program \n");
        x=in.nextInt();
        switch (x){
        case 1:
             lol test=new lol();
             test.palindromeTester("");
             test.displayInfo();
             break;
        default:
             System.out.println("Goodbye");
             break;
        }
    }
}

class lol {
    String original, reverse = "";

    public String palindromeTester(String reference) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word to Test: ");
        original = in.nextLine();
        int length = original.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        return original;
    }
    public void displayInfo() {
        if (original.equals(reverse))
            System.out.println("RESULT: A PALINDROME");
        else
            System.out.println("RESULT: NOT A PALINDROME");
        String[] arguments = new String[] {"123"};
        PalindromeTesterSamJiang1.main(arguments);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't know. I refuse to look at the code until you fix the indentations to make it human readable.

Comment: @Andreas xaxaxa nice comment ....

Answer (score 3):

You can read the input in a loop,
print an error if the input is too short,
break out when you get a valid input, for example:

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word to Test: ");
        original = in.nextLine();
        if (original.length() > 2) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Too short. Word must be at least 2 characters");
    }
```

Comment: oh, your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Enter a word to Test: ");
       original = in.nextLine();
      String[] array = original.split(" ");
      if(array.length < 2)
         System.out.print("Enter atleast 2 sentence");
```

Comment: @Guillaume yeah I know, ı just provided a solution for his problem and I commented under Janos answer that his answer is better than mine.